# Ionic 2 : Use function with QR Code reader

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to use this plugin to read QR code with Ionic 2.
I wan't to use a method or set a variable in my code when a QR code is reading.

I try that :

**My home.ts**

```
authentification_qr(){
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
          myFunction(result.text);
        },
        function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    )
  }

  myFunction(text : string) {
    alert(text);
  }
```

**My home.html**

```
<button (click)="authentification_qr()" class="authentification_button"><label>Authentification Rapide</label></button>
```

Obviously it doesn't work because I can't call a method or variable if it is outside my scan.

**Q :** How can I call method or variable in my scan ?

**PS :** I tried to write `this.myFunction(result.text)` and same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** **this** **method:**

```
authentification_qr(){
     this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
        console.log("User cancelled the action!");
        this.buttonText = "Scan";
        this.loading = false;
        return false;
      }
      console.log("Scanned successfully!");
      alert(JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
      console.log(barcodeData);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }) }
```